# How to join two data frames using regexp_replace

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, regexp-replace

I want to join two dataframes by removing the matching records using column `cust_id`. Some of the `cust_id` have leading zeros. So I need to match by removing zeros in the 'ON' clause. Tried the below query, but it's giving error in Databricks notebook.

**PS**: I don't want to create another DF1 with zeros removed.

[image]

**Query:**

```py
df1 = df1.join(df2,[regexp_replace("cust_id", r'^[0]*','')], "leftanti")
```

> Py4j.Py4JException: Method and Class java.lang.string does not exist

Comment: is leading zeros the only special case that can exists , or can be others as well ?

Comment: only leading zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works, but the output that you provided will not be reached using "leftanti" join: S15 matches S15 from another table, so it is removed too. In the example that you provided, "leftanti" join does not return any row.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'S15', 'AAA'),
     (2, '00767', 'BBB'),
     (3, '03246', 'CCC')],
    ['ID', 'cust_id', 'Name'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'S15', 'AAA'),
     (2, '767', 'BBB'),
     (3, '3246', 'CCC')],
    ['ID', 'cust_id', 'Name'])
df = df1.join(df2, df2.cust_id == F.regexp_replace(df1.cust_id, r'^0*', ''), "leftanti")

df.show()
# +---+-------+----+
# | ID|cust_id|Name|
# +---+-------+----+
# +---+-------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

No Need of square brackets `[` `]`

```
df1.join(df2, regexp_replace(df2("cust_id"), r'^[0]*', lit("")))
```

see documentatin here [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_replace(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,replacement:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)